# Matplotlib table falls outside plot area

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a table within a plot using `Matplotlib` and the table spills out past the plot area. Is there a way to make this not happen, perhaps with an offset or something similar?

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

plt.figure()
ax=plt.gca()

col_labels=['col1','col2','col3']
row_labels=['row1','row2','row3']
table_vals=[[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33]]
the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
                  colWidths = [0.1]*3,
                  rowLabels=row_labels,
                  colLabels=col_labels,
                  loc='center left')
plt.text(12,3.4,'Table Title',size=8)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Check if `plt.table` has a kwarg call `bbox_to_anchor`. If it does, then like with `plt.legend`, you'll be able to specify the position (of the anchor) of the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `bbox` parameter, in this way you can control the exact location, for example:

```
plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
                  colWidths = [0.1]*3,
                  rowLabels=row_labels,
                  colLabels=col_labels,
                  loc='center left',
                  bbox=[0.25, -0.5, 0.5, 0.3])
```

Here is the corresponding [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=table#matplotlib.pyplot.table) for `table` and the one for [bbox](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html).

Comment: That allows me to move it around, but what are those points offset from?

Comment: added a link to the documentation.